# Cocos2d: How To Create Part Of Level On RunTime For Endless Runner

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, game-engine

I am creating an 'Endless runner' using Cocos2d/Box2d where I am using CCFollow to set my camera on the main running character. (YES I am scrolling very deep in X and Y Values). Right now, I have created a part of this game which is already too  big. I am generating all the bodies/sprites at once on fixed positions. (Something Like in 1500's of the X and -1500's of the Y axis).

But it is wrong as for optimization issues and the nature of my game i.e endless runner, where I have to generate random hills of random heights at random places. May be I will use only 4 to 5 terrains and reuse them by changing the obstacles on them so they dont look repetitive.

Remember I am not using any loop to generate hills/sprites because of the complexity of terrains. I am doing it manually!

[RayWenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3888/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-1) have a great tutorial about the 'game like tiny wings' and I have looked into its 'resetHillVertices' method but it is of no help for me as I have a variety of different sprites/bodies which I have to generate on runtime at different random positions.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking to generate random sprites at random places above the terrain. If this is the case, and you are using a "connect the dots" type of terrain generation method, as Ray Wenderlich describes, you can create entries for the objects (not the actual sprites, but enough information to create them) during map generation (before gameplay).

You can use Ray's clipping method to generate the sprites as you are running, and destroy them as they pass the clipping plane behind you.

As far as placing the items randomly above the terrain, I would suggest choosing a random line of the terrain, "sliding" the item at a random point on that line, then projecting it away (toward the sky) from that line. Something like:

```
        float slope = (point2.y - point1.y) / (point2.x - point1.x);

        CGPoint randomPositionOnLine;
        randomPositionOnLine.x = point1.x + (arc4random( ) % ((int) (point2.x - point1.x)));
        randomPositionOnLine.y = randomPositionOnLine.x * slope;

        float angleOfLine = atanf(slope);

        float angleOfNormal = angleOfLine + (M_PI / 2);

        int maxHeightAboveTerrainToPlaceItem = 200;
        float heightAboveTerrain = (arc4random( ) % maxHeightAboveTerrainToPlaceItem);

        CGPoint itemPosition;
        itemPosition.x = randomPositionOnLine.x + (cosf(angleOfNormal) * heightAboveTerrain);
        itemPosition.y = randomPositionOnLine.y + (sinf(angleOfNormal) * heightAboveTerrain);
```

Comment: thanks for your input. Actually I am creating terrains by connecting lines and curves using simple box2d by using b2PolygonShape SetAsEdge method in which I have given fixed values to generate those terrain lines at that position. What I am getting by your answer is that I should check that point where two lines get clipped and I should check that to destroy previous sprite and generate next one. But I need to generate the terrains on runtime as well. What should I do for that? Plus tell me what is Ray's Clipping method? Any link for that?

Comment: So, you're essentially looking for something to cull the polygons to only display what's in your viewport? By Ray's clipping method, I was referring to the [RayWenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3888/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-1) link you posted. Is your concern about this method that it only applies to the terrain and not to other dynamic objects?

Comment: Yes exactly! Actually this method can only give me control on the vertices because in this tutorial Ray is generating terrains with the loop of hill vertices. I am using simple Box2d Polygon SetAsEdge way to create a ground on my 'terrain sprite'. Extremely manual stuff.

groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(-250/PTM_RATIO,200/PTM_RATIO),b2Vec2(-250/PTM_RATIO,50/PTM_RATIO));
    groundFixtureDef.shape = &groundBox;
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox,0);

This is the code which generates my terrain's lines and I have to use it dynamically with sprites on different positions.